# How to start My own Activity instead of mobile home screen as soon as boot completes android?

Tags: android

After boot completion i want to load my own activity as first screen instead of mobile home screen.There is a delay happening in between so how to solve this...thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 6):

check this:
[OtaStartupReceiver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/phone/OtaStartupReceiver.java)

this class is Phone apk source code in android source, please check method `private boolean shouldPostpone(Context context)`

> On devices that provide a phone initialization wizard (such as Google
>   Setup Wizard), we allow delaying CDMA OTA setup so it can be done in a
>   single wizard. The wizard is responsible for
>
> (1) disabling itself once it has been run and/or
>
> (2) setting the 'device_provisioned' flag to something non-zero and
>
> (3) calling the OTA Setup with the action below. NB: Typical phone
>   initialization wizards will install themselves as the homescreen
>   (category "android.intent.category.HOME") with a priority higher than
>   the default. The wizard should set 'device_provisioned' when it
>   completes, disable itself with the
>   PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting() and then start home
>   screen.

as above shown:

you can create a activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Demo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <!--android:priority added-->
        <!--category.HOME and DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD must have-->
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: systemProperities is not resolved, what is otautils thing which is mentioned here.it is also not resolved. so can u give some explanation and post working copy...

Comment: you dont copy the `OtaStartupReceiver` code , you just define a activity using above the xml config. ps: i give `OtaStartupReceiver` this class, want to make you understand the system choose it.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is not working. i have included the same thing in manifest. I will give you clear explanation what iam doing in my application, I have declared one broadcast Receiver as Boot_completed.from Receiver i Started one service from there iam calling my activity in this process it is taking time. you can help me out..

Comment: DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD action isn't documented anywhere in the SDK reference, what's it's purpose exactly?

Comment: @MathiasLin this is supplied for the OEM to init the device, like when you first time start your device, it will show the device setup, the setup must launched before HOME, when you finish the setup, you dont see it again until you do the factory rest.

Comment: @idiottiger Understand. So, if I get the OEM to sign my app with his platform key and eventually bundle my app with his device, and I use above intent filter with a higher priority then the Google Setup Wizard, my app would show instead of the Google Setup Wizard. Is that right? I mean, the user won't get a dialog to choose which app to use, as it's common when two activities can handle the same intent. (btw: greetings from Guangzhou, I just see you're also in China. My QQ is 1251297435)

Answer (score 1):

## I advise caution when doing this!

Before starting I think it's a good idea do enable USB debugging, so if anything happens you can fix it using ADB.

I worked in a project where the client wanted the app to appear without showing the android default home.

For this, I advise you do this with caution.
The system I used: rooted Android 4.0.3

In the manifest add this inside your activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>  <!-- this will make your app work like a launcher -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For this to work, you might want to take a look in `Settings / Applications / All`
Find "launcher", click it, and click the button `Clear Defaults`.

After that, click the "HOME" button, Android will ask you which application you want to start, if you select your app, and check the box "make default", it will always work as your Home Screen, thus, making your app the launcher. So when you restart your device, it will always display your app.

**Beware!** You might loose access to your homescreen if you do this and doesn't leave an option to access your settings again. So you'll need either to access it through ADB, or create and "escape", like I did.

Inside my app, in the Admin area I added a button that called the following:

```
public void custom_launcher(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER));
}
```

This will call Android menu, where you can go to the Settings menu again. Inside the settings menu you do the same you did to the launcher if you want to use Android default launcher again.

For this, go to `Settings / Applications / <app-name>` then click on "Clear Defaults". When you press home again, Android will ask you which launcher you want to use, Android Launcher or your app.